# Running python unit tests through python

Tags: python, unit-testing

I am working on an interface helper library for a piece of software. Software is on it's own release cycle.

I have pretty solr unit tests, but I am not using mock and require the actual software installed to test fully. Testing is currently automated through travis CI.

I want to be able to automatically test with multiple versions of python (travis is doing it now) and multiple versions of the software. I have set up a vagrant box that along with ansible deploys required versions of the software. I have also included tox to test with multiple versions of python, I am looking to test my supported versions of python with each supported version of the software automatically.

Tox now runs a shell script that sets the URL of the software endpoint in the environment and runs through all the unit tests. However, at this point I can't tell exactly what failed, as in version of software and version of python. It still requires me to manually look and review a bunch of output.

I would like to write a python script to manage testing. Does anyone know how I can invoke a unittest class object from python? Is there a better way to do this?

Thanks

Comment: I would use `virtualenv` for that

Comment: can't you just get the python script to open a `subprocess.Popen` and capture the `stdout`? (and/or the `stderr`)

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen Yes, haven't thought of that for some reason. That should work. Thanks